# JQuery: Draggable div disappears when moved to new div and Resizable evoked

Tags: jquery, draggable, contains, resizable

I have a draggable div with resizable east and west handles that is contained in a larger div and snaps to other divs.

This all works except for when I drag the div and let it snap to another div, when the resizable is evoked the draggable div dissapears.

If I drag the div to one of the other snapping divs then return it to the origination div I can resize and the div does not disappear.

I have a JS Bin for this: http://jsbin.com/xexutikeja/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `containment` in `resizable` doesn't match the one in your `draggable`, so it tries to set containment to original `parent`, but the element is over another div. Simply change your resizable for:

```
    $('#cat').resizable({
        handles: "e, w",
        containment: ".bigCat"
    })
```